# trying to use tcpdf to post from html form

Tags: php, html, pdf, post, tcpdf

Is this the correct way to "post" my data from a html form?

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($html="Job Number", $_POST["jobnum"], true, false, true, false, '', $in=1);
```

as of right now my pdfcreate.php action just goes to a blank page.

---

still not getting a response from tcpdf... Im  not really sure what I am doing wrong here..

```
 <?php

 // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
 require_once('wwwroot/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

 // create new PDF document
 $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

 // set document information
 $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
 $pdf->SetTitle('proto_addendum');
 $pdf->SetSubject('jobnum');

 // set default header data
 $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 01',  PDF_HEADER_STRING);

 // set header and footer fonts
 $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
 $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

 // set default monospaced font
 $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

 // set margins
 $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
 $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
 $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

 // set auto page breaks
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

 // set image scale factor
 $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

 // ---------------------------------------------------------

 // IMPORTANT: disable font subsetting to allow users editing the document
 $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);

 // set font
 $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', false);

 // add a page
 $pdf->AddPage();

 //data
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Job Number ", $_POST["jobnum"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Program ", $_POST["program"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Ship Date ", $_POST["shipdate"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Description ", $_POST["description"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Proto Verified By ", $_POST["name"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Additional Notes ", $_POST["notes"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "File Name", $_POST["filename1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Doc Siize ", $_POST["Docsize1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "FC ", $_POST["fc1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "DC ", $_POST["dc1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Flip ", $_POST["flip1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Quantity ", $_POST["quantity1"]);
 $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0, "Flip Quantity ", $_POST["flipqty1"]);



 // Add Javascript code
 $pdf->IncludeJS($js);

 // ---------------------------------------------------------

 //Close and output PDF document
 $pdf->Output('original.pdf', 'D');

 ?>
```

Comment: your usage of `writeHTMLCell` is wrong still. your setting the border value to `$_POST["jobnum"]` then `$_POST["program"]` etc and if the location is all 0 0 0 0 where do they fit

Comment: use one of the tutorial scripts provided with tcpdf, get it work and go from there

Comment: oh. okay i think i get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not right

[full function details](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246)

```
writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
```

so in your case, and im guessing some what:

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0,0,0,0 "Job Number ". $_POST["jobnum"]);
```

Comment: if you remove the line do you get a pdf file ?

Comment: no. I am wondering if there is a problem with the linking --see above

Comment: then the problem must be else where